# Foliations induced by Vector Fields without Singularities

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation, vector-fields, foliations

A well-known type of **foliations** is the one that is **induced by vector fields without singularities**. However, I have already read this type of foliations from **Geometric Theory of Foliations**, Page **28**. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand it very well. Therefore, I am actually looking for highly recommended references for the **foliations induced by vector fields without singularities**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the Flowbox Theorem?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, I have no idea in relation to the Flowbox Theorem. I do appreciate any help you provide.

Comment: That's the standard beginning manifolds result you need to study. You need the inverse function theorem and basic results about manifolds and flows. This is undoubtedly a prerequisite for the source you are trying to read.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you know any good references?

Comment: Spivak Volume 1 and J. Lee's Smooth Manifolds are standard.

Comment: @TedShifrin ok, what about some references for foliation induced by non-singular vector field otherwise the one mentioned above (Geometric Theory of Foliations).

Comment: I don't know any reference specifically for that. The fact that a nowhere-vanishing vector field gives a foliation is immediate from what I've already told you to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can think of foliations induced by vector fields as differential equations on manifolds (strictly speaking solutions to differential equations come with an extra natural group structure, whereas leaves of foliations have no canonical parameterization). For instance focusing on orbit equivalence instead of conjugacy as far as flows are concerned is in accordance with this perspective. In this line of thought here are two humble recommendations:

- Hirsch, Smale & Devaney's *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos*,
- Palis & de Melo's *Geometric Theory Of Dynamical Systems*.